# How to convert a String type to Float type in MySQL/PHP?

Tags: php

I have a `string` like this:

```
$foo = "1.3223";
```

How do I convert `$foo` into a `float`?

Comment: `floatval( $foo )`; - http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php

Comment: It's much faster to use `(float)$foo` instead `floatval($foo)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP String to Float](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481466/php-string-to-float)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try casting :

```
$yourFloat = (float) $foo;
```

Answer (score 3):

https://www.php.net/floatval

```
$foo = floatval($foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast it using `(float)`:

```
$foo = (float) "1.3223";
```

Answer (score 1):

This would do it:

```
<?php
$var = '122.34343The';
$float_value_of_var = floatval($var);
echo $float_value_of_var; // 122.34343
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the speech marks and PHP should convert into a float. or cast it.