# From Money to integer in PHP

Tags: php

I have a variable which value is $79.00 I need to get the 70% of this value which is *0.7 but when I try it returns 0. I have tried str_replace("$", "", $price); but still it doesn't work. any advice?

```
<?php
$price2          = woocommerce_price($product->min_variation_price); // string(6) "$79.00"
$floated        = (float) str_replace('/&.*?;/', '', $price2);    // float(79)
$seventyPercent = $floated * 0.7;                          // float(55.3)
$reFormatted    = '$' . number_format($seventyPercent, 2); // string(6) "$55.30"
?>
```

Comment: `integer` means whole number...you must be looking for `float` instead

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP String to Float](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481466/php-string-to-float)

Comment: Is not. I already tried that solution and it doesn't allow me to multiply.

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32342045/edit) to show what you have tried and what specifically goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't shared the code you're using, it's hard to know why it's not working. [As you can see](https://eval.in/426465), it's not difficult:

```
$price          = '$79.00';                                // string(6) "$79.00"
$floated        = (float) str_replace('$', '', $price);    // float(79)
$seventyPercent = $floated * 0.7;                          // float(55.3)
$reFormatted    = '$' . number_format($seventyPercent, 2); // string(6) "$55.30"
```

Comment: Didn't Worked :/ still gives me 0.00 as the number.

Comment: Str replace isn't regex - you're confusing it with preg replace