# Multiply Value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, integer, price

I have this pieces of php here...

The value that gets written in HTML is this **`$16.67`**.

I am not sure what value type this is, not sure if it is a string or integar.

Regardless, I need to take this value and increase it by `3%`.

I tried this but to no avail:

```
<?php echo $row['display_price' * 1.03]; ?>
```

If someone could help me out here this would be great.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Is the dollar sign also in `$row['display_price']` ?

Comment: Adding error reporting doesn't make sense @C0dekid.php?

Comment: You're trying to multiple *the string "display_price"* by 1.03.  Strings don't really multiply.

Comment: @Fred-ii- that's not the point, you keep posting this link on almost every post.

Comment: *Teach a person HOW to fish...* right Sam @JayBlanchard rather then just standing by the river all day long with fishing cane in hand ;-)

Comment: @C0dekid.php that ^ can be applied to you here too ;-)

Comment: @C0dekid.php: That's because on almost every PHP post the user would be able to see the problem if they just look at the error message.

Comment: *Right Ralph!* wait until he sees the comments I make on every post @Fred-ii-

Comment: @C0dekid.php *"that's not the point, you keep posting this link on almost every post."* - Yeah, so? I don't see anything from you helping the OP here. Unless you just want to throw him a fish and feed him for a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to multiple `display_price` string and use it as array key and you should just increase the value that the variable holds.

```php
echo $row['display_price'] * 1.03;
```

If variable holds the dollar sign too (**it shouldn't!**) use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3275461/4580544) regex to get the value and multiply it. Example:

```php
echo "$" . ( floatval( preg_replace( "/[^-0-9\.]/", "", $var ) ) * 1.03 );
```

Comment: What if `$row['display_price']` contains a dollar sign ? Which I believe it does.

Comment: @Daan replace it with `str_replace()` :)

Comment: @C0dekid.php I wouldn't go for `str_replace()`. Anyways that should be in the answer.

Comment: @Daan Added to answer.

Comment: The value that we are working with is a string and is proceeded by a $Dollar Sign. As such this piece of php does not know how to multiply a string and returns a null 0 value. Can someone tell me how to convert this value to an integer and remove the $ sign and then we can multiply. All help appreciated.

Comment: @RobertHenry I've edited the answer. Use second line of code.

Comment: Thanks All!!!!   So this is my returned Value = $17.1701, How do I shave off the last two decimals so that it only has two?

Comment: @RobertHenry Use [`round()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) function with `precision` set to `2`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the float value of your variable. And then, you increase it.

```
$increasedValue = floatval($row['display_price']) * 1.03;
echo '$' . $increasedValue;
```

This will return what you want, with the dollar sign at the beginning.

Comment: It won't work! `floatval()` for non-numeric leftmost characters returns `0`! Example: http://ideone.com/6z4k5M