# Alternative to integer to get number from variable including decimal but not a string

Tags: php, arrays, json, int

I have a JSON object with order information in. Within this object is an amount for example `"amount" : "82.95"`

I have this within a variable called `$amount` and I am using it within an array by doing `(int)$amount`.

The problem with this is that it is removing the `.95` which is required as it is an integer.

How can I get this value as a number and not a string not string but retain the `.95`?

Example:

```
$amount = 82.95;

echo (int)$amount;
// Result = 82
```

Comment: You do realise what casting to an integer does to a decimal, don't you? Why do you want to cast it to an integer anyway if you want to retain the decimals?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion and look up the float data type http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Comment: Sorry, I didn't write the question very well, I am looking for an alternative method than integer. I will update that now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP String to Float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481466/php-string-to-float)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $amount = "82.95";
    echo (float)$amount;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`82.95` isn't an integer, so casting it as one isn't going to return `82.95`. That type of number is a *float*:

```
$amount = '82.95';
echo (float) $amount;
// Result 82.95
```