# Best way to cast a string to a decimal/float php

Tags: php

I do have a string that contains numbers and a percentage like below:

```
 +"interactionRate": "0.00%"
```

what is the best way to cast this in float or decimal ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP String to Float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481466/php-string-to-float)

Comment: Did you tryed json_decode?

Answer (score 1):

In given case you can simply do

```
$float = (float)$string;
```

and you will got number but, have in mind that float will not be formated so for
0.00 result will be 0 (since it's same), for 0.10, result will be 0.1 etc... so if you want it to be formated on 2 decimals you need to do it with **number_format** function so it will be

```
$float_formatted = number_format( (float)$string, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$string = "1.00%";
$string = str_replace("%","",$string);
$float = (float)$string;
$result = round($float,2);
echo $result; // output 1.00
```