# How to convert Ether to Wei in PHP

Tags: math, ethereum

I am pulling data from a feed and storing this as a string. In this data I have a price in ETH which looks like this:

```
string(12) "9.9121566185"
```

I want to convert this number to WEI and store it as a [Money/Php](https://github.com/moneyphp/money) object

When I try the following:

```
$money = new Money('9.9121566185', new Currency('ETH'));
echo $money->getAmount();
```

I get the error:

```
Amount must be an integer(ish) value
```

So I am thinking I need to do the following:

1. Convert the string from ETH to WEI as an integer or 9912156618500000000
2. As the number is big, I should use [moontoast/math](https://github.com/moontoast/math)
3. Once converted, I can store the new number as WEI in the Money object
4. Go on holiday!

I am stuck on how to convert the ETH string value to a WEI value...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP String to Float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481466/php-string-to-float)

Comment: Not a duplicate, the floatVal solution is not satisfactory.

Comment: You can also use [brick/math](https://github.com/brick/math) to convert big numbers (it works with and without BCMath and GMP). If you're not locked with moneyphp/money, you can also use [brick/money](https://github.com/brick/money) which is based on brick/math and natively handles large numbers and custom currencies.

Answer (score 0):

As I am dealing with currency, something like floatVal is not going to work because a remainder or anything other than the expected value adds up over time.

So this is how I have solved the issue:

1. Get the ETH string value: string(12) "9.9121566185"
2. $bn = new \Moontoast\Math\BigNumber('9.9121566185',17); //Adds 17 decimal places
3. $bn->multiply(1000000000000000000); //multiplies out by 1.0 E+18
4. $bn2 = new \Moontoast\Math\BigNumber($bn->getValue(),0); //Chops off the remainder
5. $wei = $bn2->getValue();

The above outputs exactly:

```
string(19) "9912156618500000000"
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use parser to turn the number to money object

```
$currencies = [
 'ETH' => 18
];
$currencyList = \Money\Currencies\CurrencyList($currencies);
$parser = new \Money\Parser\DecimalMoneyParser($currencyList);
$ethMoney =$parser->parse('9.9121566185', new \Money\Currency('ETH'));
```