# PHP Float conversion fails, returns 1

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function which returns a value of `1725.00` using the `number_format(value,2)`. So, now when I convert it to `float`, it gives `1`, same for `int`,`intValue`,`floatValue`. Even I tried multiplying with 100 to get the `int` value, but it gives an error of `A non well formed numerical value`. Does anyone know what is wrong here?

```
$balance = (float) currentBalance($user_id); // currentBalance gives a value of 1725, but (float) gives makes the value 1.
print_r($balance); die; //gives 1.
```

I'm using `PHP 7.0+` and `Laravel 5.8`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP String to Float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481466/php-string-to-float)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `number_format` returns a string with commas inserted for thousand separators, so the return value from your function is `1,725.00`. When you try to cast this as a float PHP gets as far as the comma and says this is no longer a number and so returns `1`.

If you need to have a formatted string returned by `currentBalance`, your best bet is to use

```
$balance = (float)str_replace(',', '', currentBalance($user_id));
```

Otherwise, replace the call to `number_format` with a call to `round` so that `currentBalance` returns a numeric value instead.

Comment: I used `round` as well and it gives `1`.

Comment: @Rob13 you changed the call to `number_format` inside `currentBalance` to `round`? That should have worked. If it didn't, I'd need to see the code for `currentBalance` to understand why. Regardless, the use of `str_replace` I have suggested in the answer will work.

Comment: Yeah, sorry it worked, I understood something different previously. So, I read your comment again and understood this time. Your answer makes perfect sense. Thanks a lot.