# How to handle nulls when doing a sum in php

Tags: php

I have the following data of which I'm trying to sum up the total fare but php keeps throwing this error `Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in....`

```
$read_one_vehicle_response = '
                            {
                                "response_code": 0,
                                "response_message": "Request processed successfully",
                                "id": "1",
                                "ticket": [
                                    {
                                        "id": "1",
                                        "total_fare": "1000",
                                        "status": "Paid"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": "2",
                                        "total_fare": "80",
                                        "status": "Paid"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": null,
                                        "total_fare": null,
                                        "status": null
                                    }
                                ],
                                "created": "2020-09-12 15:42:29",
                                "modified": "2020-09-12 20:42:29",
                                "status": "Active"
                            }';


$income = "";

foreach (json_decode($read_one_vehicle_response, true)["ticket"] as $ticket) {

    if (is_numeric($ticket{"total_fare"})) {
       $total_fare = $ticket{"total_fare"};
    }
    else {
        $total_fare = 0.00;
    }
    $income += $total_fare;
}

echo "Total: $income";
```

I have tried the above, it adds up the numbers correctly but still keeps throwing the error. What is the correct way of handling this error? I

Comment: total_fare is string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding up string values cast them to float

```
$income = floatval(0);

foreach (json_decode($read_one_vehicle_response, true)["ticket"] as $ticket) {

    if (is_numeric($ticket{"total_fare"})) {
       $total_fare = floatval($ticket{"total_fare"});
    }
    else {
        $total_fare = 0.00;
    }
    $income += $total_fare;
}

echo "Total: $income";
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert to float or int type before do (+). Try:

```
$income += (float)$total_fare;
```

If your data can't convert to float, it will be 0.

Another way with PHP [floatval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php):

```
$income += floatval($total_fare);
```

More information and discussion in SO about [PHP String to Float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481466/php-string-to-float)

Answer (score 0):

You can do directly,

```
$income = 0;

foreach (json_decode($read_one_vehicle_response, true)["ticket"] as $ticket) {
    $total_fare = (float) $ticket{"total_fare"};

    $income += $total_fare;
}

echo "Total: $income";
```